# Wampserver: problems to load php_pdo_pgsql and php_pgsql modules

Tags: wampserver

Wampserver has a problem when loading php_pdo_pgsql and php_pgsql modules. After searching on several forums the solution is to download from http://www.bmedon.net/download.html both .dll files and overwrite the existing ones.

The problem is that it didn't work! I checked all php.ini files. I followed http://diego-loquese.blogspot.com/2010/12/conectar-wampserver-con-postgresql.html instructions (which is a summary of all the forums I found).

I am using WampServer 2.2 for Windows x64 with PHP 5.4.3

Answer (score 19):

You have to load `libpq.dll` that comes with php, in the `httpd.conf` like this:

```
LoadFile "c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.4.3/libpq.dll"
```

It worked for me

Comment: Because of the hurry I installed a ubuntu in a virtual and set my environment there. But soon as I have a minute, I will try your solution! Thanks

Comment: I literally cut and pasted that line into the bottom of my http.conf file and everything started working.  Thanks!

Comment: Excellent of you to point out that the file exists in the wamp php bundle already!

Answer (score 7):

Just copy the libpq.dll from your php directory to the apache bin directory.

Answer (score 0):

1. Install PostgreSQL
2. Edit php.ini, uncomment “extension=php_pgsql.dll”. Check both the
   php.ini in the PHP folder and Apache folder
3. Edit environment variables, add PostgreSQL /bin and /lib directories
   to Path. This solves the  issue of php_pgsql.dll not loading due to
   it not being able to resolve dependencies.
4. Done. PHP should now be able to communicate with PostgreSQL.