# PHP Connection to Postgres Not Working

Tags: php, postgresql, database-connection

I have Installed postgres and i am trying to connect to postgres but i get nothing. i tried to find the line

```
extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll
```

in my php.ini file but it does not exit but when i php -m i do see the pdo_pgsql

and when i `yum list "php*"` i get

Installed Packages

```
php.x86_64                     5.3.3-48.el6_8       @rhel-x86_64-server-6
php-cli.x86_64                 5.3.3-48.el6_8       @rhel-x86_64-server-6
php-common.x86_64              5.3.3-48.el6_8       @rhel-x86_64-server-6
php-mysql.x86_64               5.3.3-48.el6_8       @rhel-x86_64-server-6
php-pdo.x86_64                 5.3.3-48.el6_8       @rhel-x86_64-server-6
php-pear.noarch                1:1.9.4-5.el6        @rhel-6-server-rpms
php-pgsql.x86_64               5.3.3-48.el6_8       @rhel-6-server-rpms
```

Comment: I suggest you provide the code you're trying to run, along with what specifically you've tried and what specifically isn't working.

Comment: If you cannot be bothered to format you question so its readable, **why** should we bother reading it

Comment: If `extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll` does not exists....... Add it _dear liza, add it_

Comment: There are often 2 `php.ini` files. One controls the PHP CLI and the other controls PHP used with Apache.

Comment: Look at the output from `<?php phpinfo();?>` to see which `php.ini` file is being used by Apache

Comment: when i add extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll it gives me an error. no dll exists like that

Comment: Perhaps try one or more of the answers to this question?
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/11673196/2141666

Comment: I am sorted. Thank you